# Drupal 7 missing edit button on user profile page

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I've fully customized theme for Drupal 7. And on the user profile page there is no edit button. "History" field is only thing which is displayed. I understand that I did something wrong with theming. What I need to do to have this button:
[image: Missing button]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be mostly a permission issue as indicated by [Boriana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1342049/boriana). If no tabs are visible at all in your custom theme then most likely you forgot to print the  rendered tabs or task. In default Drupal theme, tabs are rendered using code `print render($tabs);` in page.tpl.php file;

If your theme is based on different theme, then you may have different variable name. For example, when I used adapative theme, I had following block which prints the tasks or tabs.

```
 <?php if ($primary_local_tasks || $secondary_local_tasks || $action_links): ?>
                <div id="tasks" class="clearfix" role="navigation">
                  <?php if ($primary_local_tasks): ?>
                    <ul class="tabs primary clearfix"><?php print render($primary_local_tasks); ?></ul>
                  <?php endif; ?>
                  <?php if ($secondary_local_tasks): ?>
                    <ul class="tabs secondary clearfix"><?php print render($secondary_local_tasks); ?></ul>
                  <?php endif; ?>
                  <?php if ($action_links = render($action_links)): ?>
                    <ul class="action-links clearfix"><?php print $action_links; ?></ul>
                  <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
              <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Ayikya thank you very much. Obivously, when you got plain template for theming you don't get tabs. Adding print render($tabs) in page--user.tpl.php solved the problem.